# Not able to fix x and y position in sigma js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js, sigma-grid-control

I tried to draw a graph in circle layout.I have given the x and y position for the nodes as follows
X=Math.cos(Math.PI*(u)/l)*R

Y=Math.sin(Math.PI*(u)/l)*R

where u is an incrementor and l is number of nodes and R is radius.
the equation seems to be correct.Problem is the graph is tilted to left side.

For a simple graph also(for two nodes) edge is not in the horizontal position,
I think the position of x and y is changed in some other function call(sigma libraries)

Can anyone help me in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the animate.html example into sigma.js, there is an example of 'circle graph'.

And the correct formula is :

```
circular_x: L * Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / N ),
circular_y: L * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / N ),
```

Where

- L : is the
- radius i : the index N : the numbe
- r of node

If I use this code, and I generate a graph of two node, edge is horizontal.

I used sigma v1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, but @logisima answer didn't solve mine.

Sometimes, this issue could be a result of the node key. **A Graph Nodes** are expected to have unique keys.

> Make sure your keys are unique

```
const allNodes = [{
  key: '1' // UNIQUE,
  name: 'anyname 1',
  label: 'LABEL1',
  x: Math.random() * 2 // LENGTH OF ALL NODES,
  y: Math.random() * 2 // LENGTH OF ALL NODES,
},
{
  key: '2' // UNIQUE,
  name: 'anyname 1',
  label: 'LABEL1',
  x: Math.random() * 2 // LENGTH OF ALL NODES,
  y: Math.random() * 2 // LENGTH OF ALL NODES,
}]
```